# Tag synonym proposal: [it] --> [информатика]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I don't yet have the required stats to use the [Tag Synonyms page](https://russian.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), but I have a simple (and hopefully straightforward) proposal.

The tag [it](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it) (5 questions) should be made a synonym of [информатика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) (21 questions):

[it](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it) --> [информатика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

---

Both tags appear to have been used for questions on the same topic:  terminology in the field of information technology / computer science.
(The [computer-science](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) tag is already a synonym of [информатика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0))

Answer (score 0):

*Информатика* is not really used these days, and when it is, it means "computer science".

The Russian terms are *информационные технологии* (quite a mouthful), *ИТ* (rarely used) and *айти* (widely used and universally understood in colloquial speech, but too ugly as a Russian word to my liking).

Comment: So... you don't think the tags should be synonymised? Or are you saving it should go the other way around?  Maybe [computer-science] should be the master tag.